# HTML 5 JS Audio Player, Play when clicking list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am hacking up an html 5 audio player I found, and I'm just adding some luxury functionality if you will-- trying to learn at the same time.

I have a player that works fine, and the cursor changes to a pointer when you hover over a list item in the playlist, but when you click nothing happens.

Here's the code I tried to implement, which gets audio to play but on what the currently selected item is. I'm not sure how to get the audio api to select the list item I'm clicking on, change the active class to that item, and play the audio from that list item.

PLAYER HTML:

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="audio-img">
                <img class="cover">
            </div>
            <div id="audio-player">
                <div id="audio-info">
                    <span class="artist"></span> - <span class="title"></span>
                </div>
                <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5">
                <br>
                <div id="audio-controls">
                    <button id="prev"></button>
                    <button id="play"></button>
                    <button id="pause"></button>
                    <button id="stop"></button>
                    <button id="next"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div id="tracker">
                    <div id="progressbar">
                        <span id="progress"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span id="duration"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <ul id="playlist">
                    <li song="Maryland.mp3" cover="bvh.jpg" artist="Alex Gray">'Maryland' <span class="floatright"><button class="download" >Download</button></span></li>
                    <li song="Hit-Time.wav" cover="bvh.jpg" artist="Alex Gray">'Hit Time' <span class="floatright"><button class="download" >Download</button></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

//Click Song Title
Javascript I tried to add to make it play on click of a list item. It plays, play button hides pause button shows and duration comes in, but only for the currently selected list item, not the one you click on. Trying to figure out how to call for the song when clicking a certain list item. Full JS below. Also uses jquery.

```
var audio;

//hide pause button

$('#pause').hide();
$('#duration').hide();

//Initialize
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

//Initializer Function
function initAudio(element){
    var song=element.attr('song')
    var title=element.text();
    var cover=element.attr('cover');
    var artist=element.attr('artist');


    //Create AUDIO OBJECT
    audio = new Audio('http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' + song);

    if(!audio.currentTime) {
        $('#duration').html('0.00');
    }

    $('#audio-player .title').text(title);

    $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

    //Insert Cover

    $('img.cover').attr('src', 'http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/img/covers/'+ cover);

    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#noThanks").click(function(){
        $("#contactdiv").hide();
    });
    $(".download").click(function(){
        $("#contactdiv").show();
    });
    $("#sendMail").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "mailto:alexgray410@gmail.com?subject=Contact%20A1%20Alex%20About%20-%20" + title;
        $("#contactdiv").hide();
    })
});
}
//Click Song Title

$('#playlist li').click(function(){
    audio.play();

    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});


//Play button

$('#play').click(function(){
    audio.play();

    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});

//Pause button

$('#pause').click(function(){
    audio.pause();

    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//Audio Stop Function

$('#stop').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#duration').fadeOut(400);
});

//NEXT Buttomn 

$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    if ($('#play').show = true){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

//PREV Buttomn 

$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    if ($('#play').show = true){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

//Volume Control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});



//Time duration

function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
        //Get Hours & Minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime)/ 60) % 60;
        //Add 0 if less than 10
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+ s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + '.' + s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration)* audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width', value+'%')
    });
}

// DOWNLOAD POP UP SCRIPT
```